# Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call `holder.getAdapterPosition()` to look it up later erorrr

Tags: java, android

```
private RecyclerView siparisList;
private DatabaseReference siparisRef;
    

    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_yeni_siparis);
    
    
        siparisRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Siparis");
        siparisList=findViewById(R.id.siparis_list);
        siparisList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AdminSiparis> options=
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AdminSiparis>()
                        .setQuery(siparisRef,AdminSiparis.class)
                        .build();
    
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdminSiparis,AdminSiparisViewHolder> adapter=
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdminSiparis, AdminSiparisViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdminSiparisViewHolder holder,int position, @NonNull AdminSiparis model) {
                        holder.kullanıcıİsmi.setText("İsim:"+model.getIsim());
                        holder.kullanıcıTelefon.setText("Telefon:"+model.getTelefon());
                        holder.kullanıcıToplamTutar.setText("Toplam Miktar:"+model.getToplamMiktar()+"TL");
                        holder.kullanıcıTarih.setText("Siparis Tarih:"+model.getTarih()+""+model.getZaman());
                        holder.kullanıcıGonderiAddress.setText("Address:"+model.getAddress()+","+model.getIl());
    
    
                        holder.siparisGosterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String kID=getRef(position).getKey();
    
    
    
    
                                Intent intent=new Intent(AdminYeniSiparisActivity.this,AdminKullaniciUrunActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("kid",kID);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
    
                    }
    
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public AdminSiparisViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.siparis_layout,parent,false);
                        return new AdminSiparisViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };
        siparisList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
        
    
    }
    
    
    public static class AdminSiparisViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView kullanıcıİsmi,kullanıcıTelefon,kullanıcıToplamTutar,kullanıcıTarih,kullanıcıGonderiAddress;
        public Button siparisGosterBtn;
    
        public AdminSiparisViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
    
            kullanıcıİsmi=itemView.findViewById(R.id.siparis_kullanıcı_adı);
            kullanıcıTelefon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.siparis_telefon_numarası);
            kullanıcıToplamTutar=itemView.findViewById(R.id.siparis_toplam_fiyat);
            kullanıcıGonderiAddress=itemView.findViewById(R.id.siparis_address_il);
            kullanıcıTarih=itemView.findViewById(R.id.siparis_tarih_saat);
            siparisGosterBtn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.siparis_kontrol_btn);
    
        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error like this I tried getAdapter Position but it still creates problems

Answer (score 0):

According to [RecyclerView.onBindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onbindviewholder_1) documentation, it states:

> RecyclerView will not call this method again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined

So for your code the optimal solution will be changing the onClickListener of `siparisGosterBtn`  like below:

```
holder.siparisGosterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         String kID=getRef(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey(); --> // change position to holder.getAdapterPosition()
         Intent intent=new Intent(AdminYeniSiparisActivity.this,AdminKullaniciUrunActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("kid",kID);
         startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
```

Comment: How can I optimize my  siparisGosterBtn? can you help me?